# How to use the ternary operator inside an interpolated string?

Tags: c#, .net, ternary-operator, string-interpolation, c#-6.0

I'm confused as to why this code won't compile:

```
var result = $"{fieldName}{isDescending ? " desc" : string.Empty}";
```

If I split it up, it works fine:

```
var desc = isDescending ? " desc" : string.Empty;
var result = $"{fieldName}{desc}";
```

Comment: @Sinatr Updated link: http://thebillwagner.com/Blog/Item/2015-07-05-StringInterpolationandtheConditionalOperators

Comment: The same applies to the [namespace alias qualifier (::)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htccxtad.aspx).

Comment: Roslyn team related discussion: [Strange syntax error in interpolated string when using ?:](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/12214)

Answer (score 1104, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated):

> The structure of an interpolated string is as follows:
>
> `{ <interpolationExpression>[,<alignment>][:<formatString>] }`

The problem is that the colon is used to denote formatting, like:

```
Console.WriteLine($"The current hour is {hours:hh}")
```

The solution is to **wrap** the conditional in parenthesis:

```
var result = $"Descending {(isDescending ? "yes" : "no")}";
```

Comment: Even more interesting example is this one when you need to use a nested interpolation string:  `Console.WriteLine($"Cargo Weight: {(ship.WeightAvailable ? $"{ship.Weight:0.00}" : "n/a")}");`

Comment: another example, ternary if with string interpolation in the condition:
var foo = $"{x.Title} {(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.SubTitle) ? $"({x.SubTitle})" : string.Empty)}";

Comment: @Jan And yet even the example you give doesn't compile, and yet ReSharper has no problem disambiguating it (since it knows to offer a code fix).

Comment: @MgSam It would help if you tell the error and your development setup. I tested my example again (copy/paste it) using VS2019 and VS2022 using .NET Core 2 till .NET Core 6 and also .NET 2 to .NET 4.8. All compiled fine (if you have a `Ship` class with a `bool WeighAvailable` and `double Weight` public properties/attributes of course).