# C#: ternary expressions inside interpolation are invalid

Tags: c#, mono, interpolation

I want to insert a ternary expression into a interpolation, like this:

```
var a = $"we have {true ? "a":"b"}";
```

Software used in compilation:

```
XBuild Engine Version 14.0
Mono, Version 5.2.0.215
```

And I used `xbuild Cmc.sln`(Cmc is my solution name). After that I got error (line 44 is the C# code given above):

```
Expr/Expression.cs(44,13): error CS8076: Missing close delimiter '}' for interpolated expression started with '{'.
Expr/Expression.cs(44,25): error CS1003: Syntax error, ':' expected
Expr/Expression.cs(44,25): error CS1733: Expected expression
Expr/Expression.cs(44,27): error CS1002: ; expected
Expr/Expression.cs(44,28): error CS1002: ; expected
```

Why do I get this? I think my code is valid.

Comment: Yeah, It's duplicate... But I searched `C# tenary` and I didn't get answer. So I opened a new question... Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$"we have {(true ? "a":"b")}";
```

Comment: Wow thank you! But why? Do you know the reason why I got error without brackets?

Comment: The explanations in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31844058/how-to-use-the-ternary-operator-inside-an-interpolated-string apply

Comment: Yeah I've just viewed that... But anyway thanks.