# Prevent ReSharper from removing essential parentheses within interpolated string

Tags: c#, resharper, string-interpolation

If you have an interpolated string where the value depends on an inline ternary operator, parentheses are needed so the full string itself is not terminated with ", as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31844059/1061602), e.g.

```
var example = $"My example is {(someBoolean ? "true string" : "false string")}";
```

Unfortunately, with my team's current ReSharper formatting options, using 'Reformat Code', shortcut CTRL+ALT+ENTER, these parentheses are removed, leaving you with:

```
var example = $"My example is {someBoolean ? "true string" : "false string"}";
```

and the error `A conditional expression cannot be used directly in a string interpolation because the ':' ends the interpolation. Parenthesize the conditional expression.`.

**Q: does anyone know which setting in ReSharper I can change to prevent this?**

I tried 'Removed remove redundant parentheses' under Code Cleanup this did not work.

Comment: What versoin of R# are you using? It doesn't do that in mine.

Comment: 2018.1.1, although it may not do it with the default options

Comment: Interesting. I'm on 2017.3.1 because I've not had a chance to install the new version. I can upgrade now actually, will report back if it breaks...

Comment: Upgraded to 2018.1.2 and it still works fine.

Comment: It must be a non-default setting. Normally Reformat just fixes things like new lines, spaces, indents, and Code Cleanup (CTRL+C+E) is more 'aggressive'... so I'm really not sure what is causing it.