# Condition within string definition

Tags: c#

I used to write this

```
if (condition)
{
    str = "A";
}
else
{
    str = "B";
}

finalstr = "Hello "+str;
```

I wonder if there is a better way.

What I want is

```
finalstr = "Hello "+ if (condition) {str = "A"} else {str = "B"};
```

or

```
finalstr = "Hello "+ condition ? "A" : "B";
```

Something like `$var = "Hello ".if(condition)...` in php.

Is there a similar way to put a condition right into a string?

Comment: You were there -- it's just a precedence issue. `finalstr = "Hello " + (condition ? "A" : "B");`

Comment: You're looking for [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated): `finalstr = $"Hello { (condition ? "A" : "B") }";`

Comment: @DM example is the proper way of doing things with strings, get used to it

Comment: @Wyck https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31844058/how-to-use-the-ternary-operator-inside-an-interpolated-string - You can't use a ternary expression directly in string interpolation because the colon (`:`) is already used for format strings.

Comment: I think this if-else is pretty good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
finalstr = "Hello " + (condition ? "A" : "B");
```

or

```
finalstr = $"Hello { (condition ? "A" : "B") }";
```

or using `string.Format`

```
finalstr = string.Format("Hello {0}", condition ? "A" : "B");
```

or you can create an extension that suits your needs:

```
public static class StringExtension
{
    // it's not needed since C# supports ternary, but I did it anyway 
    public static string If(this string str, Func<string, string> condition)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str) ? str : $"{str} {condition(str)}";
    }
}
```

then you can do this:

```
finalstr = "Hello".If(x => x == str ? "A" : "B");
```

Answer (score -1):

On simple numeric example of condition, for more then 2 outcomes:

```
var c = 1; // Algorithm / console input / etc...

var result = "hello " + c switch
{
    1 => "variant a",
    2 => "variant b",
    _ => "default variant if there is no specific match"
};
```

Said condition does not have to be numeric, this pattern works with basically everything else.

Comment: This is still going to be rather more complex than either of the options in the comments, for the question which was asked - i.e. based on a Boolean condition.