# Blazor MudTable - Null Dates in Table

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

Can anyone please advise how I can set the date value in a row to "" if the source data is a null date (01/01/0001)

I have tried this way with no luck..

```
<MudTd DataLabel="EndDate" Style="width: 160px">@row.EndDate == @null ? '' : @Convert.ToDateTime(row.EndDate).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")</MudTd>
```

Regards
Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that syntax to work (using the [conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)), you need to wrap the whole expression in script block, this is the same rule for [string interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31844059/1690217):

```
<MudTd DataLabel="EndDate" 
       Style="width: 160px">
    @(row.EndDate == null ? "" : Convert.ToDateTime(row.EndDate).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
</MudTd>
```

Given that you are casting to a date, is the value even null in the first place? if it is a string, try IsNullOrEmpty / IsNullOrWhiteSpace ...

```
<MudTd DataLabel="EndDate" 
       Style="width: 160px">
    @(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row.EndDate) ? "" : Convert.ToDateTime(row.EndDate).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
</MudTd>
```

If the value is a *nullable* `DateTime?` then do not use `Convert.ToDateTime` or [conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) (in-line if expression), just use `String.Format` which will implicitly convert a null value to an empty string:

```
<MudTd>@String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", @row.EndDate)</MudTd>
```

Try this in MudBlazor here: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QkcRFPmgFqxqgoRW

Comment: Ahh i see, I'll try that thanks, and yes is a null value not a string so it gets pulled in a  a null date.